# How to retrieve a parameter value that's not set in the report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm working in report builder, calling a stored procedure that has a parameter that, when null, sets itself to a certain value.  I want to display what this parameter is set to on the report.  From experimenting, Report Builder's parameter collection only shows the parameter as it is sent from the report.

Alternatives that I've considered but can't get to work or are sub-optimal:

1. Adding the parameter to the select statement.  The main drawback is this won't display a value if there are no results.
2. Using a return value or output parameter.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do this.
3. Re-creating the "null" logic in the stored procedure.  The correct output is displayed but this is a code fork.

How can I display this value?  Is there a way to show a return value or output value?

Comment: Is the parameter being used to filter a column?

Comment: @scsimon I tried adding the parameter as a column and binding a textbox to the column but as I said in #1 this won't show a value if there are zero results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the procedure to return the parameter value in a UNION ALL select so that a row with the parameter value will always be returned.   That row could have NULL for all the other columns so that you can filter it out in the rest of the report.

Another possibility is to add a second dataset to the report that does nothing but get the value of the parameter based on what you pass.  That, however, is also a sort of code fork.  The fork could be mitigated, however, by putting it in a UDF, and resourcing the same UDF in both datasets.

Yet another possibility is to replicate the logic of populating the parameter in a Custom Code block in the report.  However, that is also a code fork.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked in Report Builder interface but I do have quite a bit of experience building reports in BIDS/VS... There it's a simple matter of setting the parameter default, in the rdl, to match the default in the stored procedure.